# Combining Excel tables in SAS that have different columns

Tags: import, sas

I have about 6 Excel files that I need to combine, preferably in SAS. The issue is that each Excel file has different columns. I want to create a table that has the data from all the tables into one big table.

I was thinking that I can import each file and then stack the tables together with all columns used in all tables. Is this possible to do? How could I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

After reading into SAS you can something like below. it will append the datasets with same names, where ever you have different columns, you will have missing values.

```
 data final;
   set one two three four five six;
run;
```